# Delete or Remove

Tags: difference, word-difference

What is the difference between `delete` and `remove` word meaning?

When I should use `delete` and when `remove`? And is there any other synonyms?

Comment: Perhaps you can refine your question a little - showing you have examined dictionary definitions for both words and clarifying what it is that you don't understand about those definition.

Comment: Depends on the context your referring too, maybe you should elaborate on your question a little.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/52508/16833

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*'Remove'* has a broad context. You can remove a cat from a room, remove a word from a document, remove an actor from the stage, remove makeup from her face, remove yourself from my presence...

However, *'delete'* is much more limited. We usually only use 'delete' in a technological or compositional context, such as a word from a document, a line of code from a program, an object from a drawing. You can delete a picture of a house from your computer, but you can't delete an actual house.